# Understanding a coin tossing problem

Tags: probability

**The question:** If we toss a coin 4 times, what are the chances of seeing 2 heads?

**The approach:** Introducing a random variable $X, S_{x}=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ would easily show us that $P(X=2)=\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{2^4}=0.375$ (basically the PMF of a binomial distribution).

Now the problem is that my intuition, considering the 50% chance of seeing a head in a single toss, suggests a 50% chance of seeing head/tails being evenly split regardless of the number of tosses.

Obviously my intuition is wrong as the chance of seeing head/tails being evenly split decreases as we increase the number of tosses. So can someone explain the situation so that I understand what I'm "doing" wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are many more possible results when you throw more coins.  If you throw $100$ coins, the most likely result is $50$ heads, but $49$ heads and $51$ heads are not far behind.  Clearly $50$ cannot be half the time, or the sum of the three would be greater than $1$.